# Transitive dependencies not resolved when dependency version defined in parents dependencyManagement

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I've got a multi-module project with layout as below:

```
pom.xml
projA
  trunk
    pom.xml
    projA1
      pom.xml
    projA2
      pom.xml
```

In the parent's pom I've defined `dependencyManagement` and `properties`:

```
<properties>
  <javaee-api.version>6.0</javaee-api.version>
  <log4j.version>1.2.11</log4j.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>  
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>  
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javaee-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

pom.xml for projA2 contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

pom.xml for projA1 contains:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>projA2</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In projA1 I'm using log4j but the dependency is transitive (from projA2).

Now when I run `mvn dependency:tree -X` I get:

```
[WARNING] Invalid POM for mypackage:projA2:jar:1.0, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax:javaee-api:jar is missing. @ line 37, column 15
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for log4j:log4j:jar is missing. @ line 56, column 15
```

but just below this lines I get:

```
[DEBUG]   testArtifact: artifact=log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.11:compile
[DEBUG]   includeArtifact: artifact=log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.11:compile
[DEBUG]   startProcessChildren: artifact=log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.11:compile
[DEBUG]   endProcessChildren: artifact=log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.11:compile
[DEBUG]   testArtifact: artifact=javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
[DEBUG]   includeArtifact: artifact=javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
[DEBUG]   startProcessChildren: artifact=javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
[DEBUG]   endProcessChildren: artifact=javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
```

The only solution is to specify log4j version (`<version>${project.version}</version>`) in projA2 pom.xml.

Question: what am I doing wrong :-(? I don't want to specify versions that are already defined in parent's `dependencyManagement` section.

Answer (score 8):

I has faced same problem. In my case if forgot update parent POM in local repository. Try to do

```
mvn install
```

for parent module.

Comment: If you want to build a parent module without all of its children, use "mvn install -N"

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue. Removing (manually) all the projects involved from the local repository and run "mvn clean install" later worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

needs to be in `/projA/trunk/pom.xml` instead of `/projA/trunk/projA2/pom.xml`.

Of course, if you want this be available across all your projects and not just projA it has to be in `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't want to add this dependency to all projects in projA. There are more then two projects, so your solution will not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I defined a property in my settings.xml and used this for systemPaths  in dependencies in my poms and my parent pom. The ignore of the "invalid" package leads to compile errors, because packages used as transitive dependencies are missing in the classpath.

I found (transfered to your problem), that if I call maven with "mvn -Dlog4j.version=2.1.11" the warning disappears and also the compile errors. For me this is no satisfieing solution but it solves the problem with invisible transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as the OP. It turns out it was a maven bug, as updating to the newest maven version (3.3.3 as of writing) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It can be repository problem search your missing dependencies find out right repositories and add to you pom like this:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-3rd-party-releases</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

To the `dependencyManagement` section of the parent POM (just as you did with JUnit).  Any children that require log4j may specify a dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

without the version, and it will work, because the version will be pulled from the parent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know that it should work, but it does not want to work ;/...